# Limit inferior of a function that diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

So I have a function like  $f(x) = x$, that clearly diverges to infinity. It seems logical that the limit superior would not exist as well. But does the limit inferior exist? At first I was thinking that each real number could be a limit inferior but other people told me it doesn't exist just like the limit superior, so I'm not sure any more.

Answer (score 1):

I do assume you are looking at $x\rightarrow\infty$
By definition,

$$\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\inf_{x>n} x) =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n=\infty$$